# Why might a virtual link work, but the actual folder not work? (Linux and Vagrant)

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, symlink

This is at least to me a very mysterious mystery.

I am running a `Vagrant` box running Ubuntu 14 Linux, and a standard LAMP stack.  There is no `.htaccess` file.

If I have a folder `/Library/css` and call any page of any type in it I get `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.  *BUT*, if I rename the folder `css-actual` and then do:

```
ln -s css-actual css # symbolic link
```

Everything works.  This behavior is baffling, any ideas?  It's like there's "something" saying "hey, I won't serve content from a folder named /Library/css, but I'll serve it through a symlink."  Never experienced before.